# Match a node if it has a certain attribute and its parent has the same attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

OK, I have a finding aid structure like so:

```
<c01 level="file">

<c02 level="file"></c02>

</c01>
```

For my XSLT template, I'd like to be able to match only nodes with the attribute of level="file" that have a parent also with the attribute of level="file" so that I can enact some specific formatting on the child.

Normally to match level="file" I just use the following:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@level="file"]">
```

However, for the purposes of formatting (indentation, etc), I need the node that is a child of a node with the same attribute to be treated differently than its parent. So something like:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@level="file"] and parent::[@level="file"]">
```

Any ideas? I hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@level='file' ]/*[@level='file']">
```

This template matches any element the string value of whose `level` attribute is `"file"` and that is a child of an element the string value of whose `level` attribute is `"file"`

**Do note**: No `..` or `parent::` axis or `//` are used and this is probably the simplest and most precise match pattern.

Comment: Do you think this snippet will overrule matches on `*[@level='file' ]`? That's the problem I'm currently having. Getting this line to affect nodes like `*[@level='file' ]/*[@level='file']/did` when I already have `*[@level='file' ]/did` in the stylesheet as well.

Comment: @librarion: Yes, this match pattern is more specific. If it isn't selected, then specify `priority="3"`

Answer (score 1):

Match on any node whose parent has the same @level attribute as myself, and my @level attribute = 'file'

```
<xsl:template match="*[../@level=./@level][./@level='file']">
 ...
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Does this work if I already have another section matching the parent with `<xsl:template match="*[@level="file"]">`? Or would they conflict?

Comment: My understanding is the more specific match wins - I'd don't have my Michael Kay XSLT book to hand, but I recall there is a weighting which applies to determine the order which matches match.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Last thing: What if I have children underneath it? As in, can I then further match `<xsl:template match="*[../@level=./@level][./@level='file']/scopecontent">`, or is that going to freak it out?

Comment: which node do you want to be your matched node? the scopecontent or it's parent? You need to consider the match as a path with [filter] - so the path part matches the selection of nodes e.g. 'foo' - all nodes call foo, and a filter [ @attribute = 'bar' ][baz] - which have an attribute of bar, and a child node of baz. - so in your example your are matching on the 'scope content' node which is one below any node which matches your previous criteria.