# Match ANY node that has a certain attribute and whose parent has the same attribute?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsl-fo

So a while back I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056547/match-a-node-if-it-has-a-certain-attribute-and-its-parent-has-the-same-attribute) about matching a child of level "file" that has a parent of level "file". The solution was as follows:

```
 <xsl:template match="*[@level='file' ]/*[@level='file']">
```

This worked at the time, but I now realize I need to match beyond a second level. So in addition to matching this:

```
 <c01 level="file">
   <c02 level="file"></c02>
 </c01>
```

I further need to match this and beyond:

```
<c01 level="file">
  <c02 level="file">
     <c03 level="file"></c03>
  </c02>
</c01>
```

In short, is there a way to match ANY node in the document of level "file" that has a direct parent of level "file" no matter the depth? I need this to specify indentation in an xsl-fo document. I really just need my stylesheet to continue indenting children further than their parents.

I hope this make a modicum of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//*[@level="file" and ../*[@level="file"]]
```

This XPath expression matches any node with `level="file"` whose parent also has `level="file"`. Is it what you need?

Comment: Thanks, that does match correctly. Looks like I also have some other issues in the stylesheet to sort out.